# Changing the Values of Nested Maps Within Maps

Tags: java, tree, hashmap, snakeyaml

I was creating a library in java that manages YAML objects, sets and changes data in a given path. I'm using snakeyaml as a dependency. SnakeYAML wraps key-value pairs in a map. If the value is also a map, it'll create a nested path.

```
parent:
  child1:
    grandchild: 3
  child2: 18
```

The problem is, assuming that you don't know the structure, how can you create another child under `child1`?

---

In the code below, I tried to do just that. However, please note that this is one of my many innumerable tries.

```java
private static Map set(String key, Object o, List<String> paths, Map<Object, Object> map, Map<Object, Object> prev, int loops) {
        if (map.size() == loops + 1) {
            prev.put(key, o);
            return prev;
        }
        for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {
            prev.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            if (entry.getKey().equals(paths.get(loops)) &&
                    (entry.getValue() instanceof Map || entry.getValue() instanceof Node)) {
                return set(key, o, paths, map, prev, loops + 1);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

---

#### Expected Outcomes

When calling `set("grandchild2", 8, Arrays.asList("parent", "child1"), map, new LinkedHashMap<>(), 0);`, the method returned `grandchild2: 3` instead of:

```
parent:
  child1:
    grandchild: 3
    grandchild2: 8
  child2: 18
```

### The Entire Code

```java
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("E:\\test.yml");

        DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
        options.setDefaultFlowStyle(DumperOptions.FlowStyle.BLOCK);


        Map m2 = set("grandchild2", 8, Arrays.asList("parent", "child1"), map, new LinkedHashMap<>(), 0);
        String result = new Yaml(options).dump(m2);
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, result, Charset.defaultCharset());
        System.out.println(m2);
    }


    private static Map set(String key, Object o, List<String> paths, Map<Object, Object> map, Map<Object, Object> prev, int loops) {
        if (map.size() == loops + 1) {
            prev.put(key, o);
            return prev;
        }
        for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {
            prev.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            if (entry.getKey().equals(paths.get(loops)) &&
                    (entry.getValue() instanceof Map || entry.getValue() instanceof Node)) {
                return set(key, o, paths, map, prev, loops + 1);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**Any help would be appreciated!**